# Query Custom Angular Components in Unit Tests

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

Is it possible for me to query a custom Angular component in my unit tests?

For example, I have the following component:

```
<div class="my-custom-checkbox-group">
    <my-checkbox
        class="my-custom-checkbox" 
        (click)="onClick()">
    </my-checkbox>
    <span>...</span>
</div>
```

In my unit test, I am trying to do the following:

```
it('should mark field as disabled when checkbox is ticked', async(() => {
    // Arrange
    fixture.detectChanges();
    de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.my-custom-checkbox-class'));

    const field: AbstractControl = component.myForm.controls['myField'];

    // Act
    el.click();

    // Assert
    expect(field.valid).toBeFalsy();
}));
```

But I get:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of null

Thoughts? Thanks

Comment: First thing first: When you use `async` you need to call the `expect` in `fixture.whenStable().then(() => { // wait for async getQuote
    fixture.detectChanges();        // update view with quote
    expect(el.textContent).toBe(testQuote);
  });`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a dot (.) after css('.my-custom-checkbox-class').
Try `de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.my-custom-checkbox-class'));`

First thing first: When you use `async` you need to call the `expect` in

`fixture.whenStable().then(() => { // wait for async getQuote
    fixture.detectChanges();        // update view with quote
    expect(el.textContent).toBe(testQuote);
  });`

Either you can call `fakeAsync` instead of `async` and instead of `fixture.whenStable().then` you can do.

`tick()`;
`fixture.detectChanges()`;

```
it('should mark field as disabled when checkbox is ticked', fakeAsync(() => {
     tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.my-custom-checkbox-class'));

    de.triggerEventHandler('click', null);

    tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    // Assert
}));
```

Comment: I've tried both ways. I should've mentioned this earlier. I've been told to try and do `fixture.detectChanges()` beforehand to see if that would work but it hasn't.

Comment: then do `fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('ctx-checkbox')).` Maybe it does not work as it on the bespoke component. You have to call `fixture.detectChanges()` after clicking the button before the `expect`

Comment: What is your component changeDetectionStrategy? Is that OnPush? Do you have any if wrapped around the component?

Comment: It is set to the default

Comment: If you add a bit more code, I might be able to help. Do you have any if wrapped around the component?

Comment: I've gone ahead and added some more code, hopefully that can help.